# Python regex to match alphanumeric starting with capital letter and length range

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to match strings like these:

```
NEV2297075
WB/03/001/585269
WB/03/HK/585065
```

It should start with 2 or more capital letters and end with a number, can contain A-Z,/ and numbers in between and total length should be between 10 and 22

For this I used:

```
re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2,}[A-Z\/0-9]{1,}[0-9]{10,22}'
```

I see that the length range is applying to the expression immediately preceding it. How to apply length range to entire string?

Comment: You can't.  You can limit the length of the numeric string, but not the overall length.  You'd have to do that in post processing, by checking the length of the "match" objects you get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifier here `[0-9]{10,22}` repeats matching 10 - 22 digits.

If you want to verify the number of total characters, you should anchor the string and verify the number of characters until the next anchor using a lookahead `^(?=[A-Z\d,/]{10,22}$)`

```
^(?=[A-Z\d,/]{10,22}$)[A-Z]{2,}[A-Z\d,/]*\d$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rnBx0w/1)